# in laravel how to search student data by ( "registor no" and "joing date" )and display student name, fname, mname, lname in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

any one guide me how to do this

**this is input view,** 
[image]

**output come in view like this with student data** 
[image]

**my model**
Student.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'student_lists';
    // protected $dates = ['certificate_issue_date','date_of_join','date_of_completion','dob'];

    protected $fillable = ['student_name', 'student_registration_id', 'date_of_join', 'student_phone_no', 'student_photo' ];

}
```

**my route**

```
Route::any ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $user = Student::where ( 'student_registration_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
    if (count ( $user ) > 0)
        return view ( 'my-search' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
       else
         return view ( 'my-search' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found.  Try to search again !' );
} );
```

**my view**

> {{ csrf_field() }}
>     
>                @if(isset($details))
>
> The Search results for
>   your query    are :
>
> ### Sample User details
>
> Name Email
>   Photo    @foreach($details as $user) 
>   {{$user->name}} {{$user->email}}  student_photo }}"    class="img-circle" width="90" /> 
>    @endforeach   @elseif(isset($message))
>
> {{$message}}
>
> @endif

Comment: we would need to see your code of your models, your controller and what you tried so far

Comment: can you post your tabke migration so that we can suggest you a query to do that

Comment: @Khalid Khan i added my controller view and route

Comment: @Paladin i added

Comment: @user12380208 Everything looks fine to me. Then what problem you are facing with  this above code ?

Comment: @Khalid Khan look my model and give me solution in your way i was tried many way but i get error so guide me

Comment: @KhalidKhan in this code showing all student data wen i refresh the page and i what to passing "date of join " and "register no"  that time only display data in view

Comment: @user12380208 Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Put this is your model Students.php

```
public static function search(string $search) {
    $columns = ["student_registration_id", "date_of_join"];

    // If the search is empty, return everything
    if (empty(trim($search))) {
      return static::select($columns)->get();
    }
    // If the search contains something, we perform the fuzzy search 
    else {
      $fuzzySearch = implode("%", str_split($search)); // e.g. test -> t%e%s%t
      $fuzzySearch = "%$fuzzySearch%"; // test -> %t%e%s%t%s%

      return static::select($columns)->where("name", "like", $fuzzySearch)->get();
    }
}
```

Create one controller and paste this code there:

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
    public function type(Request $request, $search = "") {
      $search = Input::get('q');
      $user =  Student::search($search);

      return view ('my-search',compact($user));
    }
  }
```

And your route for this should be:

```
Route::get( '/search', 'SearchController@type');
```

Hopefully it'll help you

Comment: showing error "Argument 1 passed to App\Student::search() must be of the type string, null given, called in"

Comment: is input::get('q') getting anything ?

Comment: just i typed url in browser it showing error it not showing view page except error

Comment: Have you created that controller ?

Comment: @user12380208 I've updated the code above. I've just renamed the function and route. Please check if it is working

Comment: Same error ,, if possible  to you make working example code